# Showing get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) or View all posts link is not working in wordpress

Tags: posts, options

I am trying to show view all post with this link

```
<a class="btn-primary" 
href="<?php echo get_permalink( get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) );?>">View All</a>
```

It directing the correct page id, but with that page it showing home page, not working that page. **N.B.** i have set from setting>Reading Setting> posts page Blog page which is current page which is not working. any solution.

Comment: what theme are you using? does the theme have a *home.php* or *front-page.php* template?

Comment: yes, there is template called front page

Comment: i have tried those option, but not working , it showing home page

Comment: the blog page will use *index.php* or *home.php* of your theme; did you edit any of those files? what theme are you using? have you contacted the developer or asked in the theme's support forum?

Comment: i am developing wordpress site, yes the blog page using index.php file

Comment: i have also check making a sample theme, the get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) is not working there, i am using wordpress 4.6 version